# bigcommerce api pull number of visitors

Tags: bigcommerce

Is the number of visitors and conversion rates available via the API?

I can't find this in the documentation.

I need to display the daily / weekly vistors and get the conversion numbers so I can then calculate the daily / weekly conversion rates?

Mr Warby

Comment: No. Bigcommerce does not allow you to track the visitor/conversion numbers via the API. The proper tool for this is Google Anlytics.

Answer (score 0):

The number of visitors and conversion rates isn't currently available via the API.
It is already available when logged into BC however (and displayed quite nicely).

If you want to see a list of the API endpoints see [here.](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api)
(On the left under the heading 'Reference' are all the available endpoints.)

If you really need to achieve this you could use webhooks to capture all orders and add tracking to your theme to track all your customers. You could then work out your conversion rate (with the API).

Alternative as suggested by @developerscott use Google Analytics to track and work our conversion rates for you. You can then access Google Analytics over an API which will provide you with your data.